# Fibonacci Sequence when passing in pointer to integer pointer

Tags: c, pointers, sequence, fibonacci

I am trying to pass in a pointer to integer pointer with the number of values it wants. The function must edit an array of integers that is passed in.

Secondary Question: Since the array's address is being passed in, would storing in a dynamically allocated array be needed?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>    

void fib(int **fib_sequence, int values) {
    fib_sequence = malloc(values * sizeof(int)); // this line may be unnecessary
    *fib_sequence[0] = 0;
    *fib_sequence[1] = 1;
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i < values; i++) {
        *fib_sequence[i] = *fib_sequence[i-1] + *fib_sequence[i-2];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int count = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    int *fib_sequence;
    fib(&fib_sequence, count);    
    printf("%d", fib_sequence[count - 1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fib_sequence = malloc(values * sizeof(int)); *fib_sequence[0] = 0;` --> `*fib_sequence = malloc(values * sizeof(int)); (*fib_sequence)[0] = 0;`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped!

Comment: Dynamic arrays are not necessary in the following cases. E.g `int fib_seq[count]; fib(fib_seq, count);`...`void fib(int *fib_sequence, int values) { fib_sequence[0] = 0;`

Comment: `*x[y]` --> `(*x)[y]`

Answer (score 3):

Better `malloc` outside the function and save the extra level of indirection.  Also add some argument checking and use the correct type for `count`.  Don't forget to `free` your memory in the end.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>    

void fib(int *fib_sequence, int values) {
    fib_sequence[0] = 0;
    fib_sequence[1] = 1;
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i < values; i++) {
        fib_sequence[i] = fib_sequence[i-1] + fib_sequence[i-2];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <number>\n", argv[0]);
      return 1;
    }

    long count = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    int *fib_sequence = malloc(count * sizeof(int));
    fib(fib_sequence, count);    
    printf("%d\n", fib_sequence[count - 1]);
    free(fib_sequence);
}
```

It is even better to examine the value of `errno` after each statement.  This way you will receive an error message instead of segmentation fault if you input negative values.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)
#define CHKERR()                                                \
    if ( errno != 0 )                                           \
    {                                                           \
        perror("Error in " __FILE__ ":" TOSTRING(__LINE__));    \
        return 1;                                               \
    }

void fib(int *fib_sequence, int values) {
    fib_sequence[0] = 0;
    fib_sequence[1] = 1;
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i < values; i++) {
        fib_sequence[i] = fib_sequence[i-1] + fib_sequence[i-2];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <number>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    long count = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10); CHKERR();

    int * fib_sequence = malloc(count * sizeof(int)); CHKERR();

    fib(fib_sequence, count);

    printf("%d\n", fib_sequence[count - 1]); CHKERR();

    free(fib_sequence);
}
```